# Should i add a non clustered index over a clustered index table, based on this where clause and join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a parent table and a child table.

The parent table has a clustered index as primary key with increment value (`ParentID`). The child table also has a clustered index as primary key with increment value (`ChildID`)

Primary key `Parent.parentID` is in relation with `child.parentID` as a foreign key.

I join those two tables based on following query.

```
Select ....
Join on parent.parentID = child.parentID 
where parent.personalNumber = 197608134356 <-- varchar
```

Now, should I

1. add non clustered index on `parent.personalNumber` as it is in the where clause?
2. Add a non clustered index on the foreign key `child.parentiD` to speed up the join?

It would mean I put non clustered index over a clustered index table.

I expect a lot of rows on both parent and child over time. There will be inserts and selects. No updates or deletes

Thanks
/s

Comment: My suggestion is to add an index to `personalNumber`. What about the `child.parentID` it is depend on what type of join is used by optimizer. Usually, to add the index on `child.parentID` is good idea.

Comment: I would definitely add the nonclustered index on `child.ParentID` to help with the JOINs. Whether or not the NC index on `parent.PersonalNumber` will help depends on (a) how selective that `PersonalNumber` is (with a given value, how many % of the original rows will be retrieved?) and (b) what kind of columns you have in your `SELECT` clause (if you use `SELECT *` everywhere, then the usefulness of a NC index is significantly reduced)

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one clustered index on a table, and you already have one on ParentId for Parent table and one for ChildId on Child table, both are incremented values wich is good, and primary keys which is good too (not mandatory, you could choose to have your clustered index on other columns and a non clustered index on your pk).

Your design looks fine. You have to add non clustered indexes on your search columns (parent.personalNumber and others if any) and on foreign keys, it usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use clustered index for PK unless you have a compelling reason not to.

That join can still use a clustered composite PK on child
Check the execution plan - I would be very surprised if that clustered index was not used by the join

An index on the personalNumber should aid the where

Comment: a compelling reason would be that the primary key does not "increments" , which is not so rare. inserts would fragment the cluster very badly

Comment: @Alain_Deloin But it would still badly fragment a non-clustered unique index.  Granted a badly fragmented non-clustered can be more manageable but I still would tend to take the hit on the clustered.  But point taken.

Comment: you are perfectly correct, but "sometimes" it is not you who designs the database ;)

Comment: @Alain_Deloin So what if someone else designed the database?  The question was indexes to help a query.

Comment: The PK may sometimes be a column that does not increment at all: a functional code or a guid assigned by the application (not Sql sequentialId). In that case clustering on the PK may be bad (I saw it). The point is: do not ALWAYS use PK as cluster as a rule of thumb.

Comment: @Alain_Deloin Leave me alone.  I did not say to "ALWAYS use PK".  I answered "Use clustered index for PK unless you have a compelling reason not to".

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing for high performance, with many concurrent clients, all inserting into your table at the same time - you should not have a clustered index based on a PK that is also an identity column.  See this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/05/27/monotonically-increasing-clustered-index-keys-can-cause-latch-contention.aspx) for an explanation.  To do so creates a hotspot in your table which can adversely impact performance.

There is almost always a more appropriate column to base a clustered index on in a table with an identity column as a PK.